# Generate function in a loop for DifferentialEquations in Julia

Tags: julia, differentialequations.jl

Taking the Lorenz example ([JuliaDiffEq github](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DiffEqDocs.jl/blob/master/docs/src/tutorials/ode_example.md))

```
function lorenz(t,u,du)
    du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
    du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
    du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end
```

If I had to generate equations in a loop, I would try to concatenation strings in a loop and then convert them to a function. With Matlab this works ([str2func](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html?requestedDomain=in.mathworks.com)). With Julia, I’m lost (this is actually the very first thing I’m trying in Julia).
My first try was:

```
function lorenz(t,u,du)
    Ex = :(du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1]))
    eval(ex)
    du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
    du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end
```

Doesn’t work (u undefined; followed by lines of errors originating probably from the use of this function in `prob = ODEProblem(lorenz,u0,tspan)`
Could someone please point me in the right direction.
The first problem is that I was unable to find what happens to the function as it goes into the `ODEProblem`. Someone please also direct me to where I can find out what a function really is in Julia.

---

**EDIT1**

I just tried

```
ex = quote
function lorenz(t,u,du)
    du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
    du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
    du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end
end
eval(ex)
```

This works. So I know a way that this works. But I fear I might have stumbled across ‘a way’; not the preferred way. Could someone more familiar with `Julia` please comment.

---

**EDIT2**

An example of the system of equations that needs to be solved:

```
du[1] = u[1] + v[1] + U
dv[1] = v[1] + U

du[2] = u[2] + v[2] + U
dv[2] = v[2] + U

...
```

Here `U` is sum over `u[i]` (i goes from 1 till `M`; it should be possible to set the value of `M` in a variable).

Comment: You should really avoid using `eval` if you don't have to. Your issue here is that (A) eval is in the global scope and (B) you don't escape the variables into the expression. But this is definitely not the right way to approach the problem. Can you instead explain what you're trying to do so we can give a more appropriate solution? My guess is that you can do it like this, but you're only thinking about it this way because of a MATLAB brain and there's a much easier way you haven't tried.

Comment: I am solving a system with 2N equations, each with very long expressions but of a similar structure, which may be obtained with a for loop...The N may be changed depending on how much accuracy is required. With a for loop I would not have to rewrite the equations.

Comment: Why not just loop in the function? The number of equations should have `2N = length(u)` so you can use that in the function.

Comment: Right, so in each equation there is a summation term that would require me to loop over u.

Comment: That's not bad at all though. Looping in Julia is like C in terms of performance. Other than some compiler optimizations which could theoretically happen if you expand out the full equation, looping will give you full performance (in fact, the compiler will do many optimizations on the loop as well). You shouldn't unnecessarily avoid this. But if you really really want to avoid it, a closure over a generated function which dispatches on `Val{N}` would do it, but I would highly recommend just writing the loop first. Avoid loops in MATLAB, but not in Julia!

Comment: Calling a loop when defining equations of a function would work with something of the sort of a comprehension you would suggest?

Comment: Can you make your example more like the problem you're trying to solve? Doesn't have to be the same problem, but make it dependent on `N` in a similar way. I'll answer with a few things you can do, and the pros/cons of them.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Thanks Chris. Please have a look at **EDIT2**.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB you should try to avoid the loop. In Julia, looping in this kind of context is optimized so there's no reason to avoid it. An easy way to write this function is:

```
function f(t,u,du)
  U = sum(u)
  for i in eachindex(u)
    du[i] = u[i] + v[i] + U
    dv[i] = v[i] + U
  end
end
```

Notice that this doesn't even need a reference to the length, so it will work with any size `u` and `du`. So create `ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan)` where `u0` is your size `M` array and you'll be good.

We can use some performance macros to optimize this a bit more. `@inbounds` turns off bounds checking, so it can be nice to do

```
function f(t,u,du)
  U = sum(u)
  @inbounds for i in eachindex(u)
    du[i] = u[i] + v[i] + U
    dv[i] = v[i] + U
  end
end
```

In some cases, if the loop is long enough we may want to force `@simd` on it:

```
function f(t,u,du)
  U = sum(u)
  @simd for i in eachindex(u)
    @inbounds du[i] = u[i] + v[i] + U
    @inbounds dv[i] = v[i] + U
  end
end
```

or if it's really long, multithread it:

```
function f(t,u,du)
  U = sum(u)
  Threads.@threads for i in eachindex(u)
    @inbounds du[i] = u[i] + v[i] + U
    @inbounds dv[i] = v[i] + U
  end
end
```

(and make sure you [enable threading](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing#Multi-Threading-(Experimental)-1) of course).